# "Connection refused" vs "No route to host"

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, routing

I have an Apache server running on a server:

```
[root@te-srv2 ~]# ps -ecf|grep httpd
root       698 32047 TS   19 10:45 pts/24   00:00:00 grep httpd
root     32081     1 TS   19 10:16 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   32083 32081 TS   19 10:16 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   32084 32081 TS   19 10:16 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
....
```

However, when I try to connect to local host I get "Connection refused":

```
[root@te-srv2 ~]# wget http://127.0.0.1
--2014-02-24 10:46:16--  http://127.0.0.1/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:80... failed: Connection refused.
```

Same happens when I try to connect to the local IP address:

```
[root@te-srv2 ~]# wget http://132.70.6.157
--2014-02-24 10:46:40--  http://132.70.6.157/
Connecting to 132.70.6.157:80... failed: Connection refused.
```

On the other hand, when I try the same from another computer in the same network, I get a different error "No route to host":

```
[erelsgl@erel-biu ~]$ wget http://132.70.6.157
--2014-02-24 10:49:11--  http://132.70.6.157/
Connecting to 132.70.6.157:80... failed: No route to host.
```

Why am I getting these errors? And what should I do to be able to connect to the http server from both the same computer and other computers in the network?

UPDATES: Based on the comments and answers, here is some more information:

```
[root@te-srv2 ~]# traceroute 132.70.6.157
traceroute to 132.70.6.157 (132.70.6.157), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  te-srv2 (132.70.6.157)  0.082 ms  0.007 ms  0.005 ms

[erelsgl@erel-biu ~]$ traceroute 132.70.6.157
traceroute to 132.70.6.157 (132.70.6.157), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  te-srv2 (132.70.6.157)  0.446 ms !X  0.431 ms !X  0.420 ms !X

[root@te-srv2 ~]# netstat -lnp|grep http
tcp        0      0 :::443                      :::*                        LISTEN      5756/httpd
```

Comment: Can you `traceroute 132.70.6.157` from both servers and compare the output?

Comment: 443 is the SSL-ports (https). Check your configuration to ensure you listen to http port 80.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Show the output of `netstat -lnp`, so we can see which processes are actually listening to which ports on the server, and what IP addresses they are bound to.

Regarding the second computer, its network connectivity looks broken. `netstat -rn` will give some insight on the problem there.

In order to give better advice, more details regarding general network configuration and IP configuration on both computers are needed.

Edit:

You have to change your Apache configuration so that it is a HTTP server, not SSL server. Configuration files are located under /etc/apache2 most of the time.

The IP configuration and network configuration information is still needed to analyze the other problem. The traceroute information didn't reveal anything.

Comment: Indeed, there is no process listening to port  80! The Apache server listens on port 443. But why is this?

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi: typically, 80 is HTTP, 443 is HTTPS (unless you change those default ports). So maybe the application only expects HTTPS ?

Comment: Thanks to netstat, we found out that this was really a configuration problem in Apache.

Answer (score 33):

"Connection refused" means that the target machine actively rejected the connection.
With port 80 as the context, one of the following things is likely the reason:

- Nothing is listening on 127.0.0.1:80 and 132.70.6.157:80
- Nothing is listening on *:80
- The firewall is blocking the connection with REJECT

So check your Apache and iptables config.

"No route to host" refers to a network problem. It is *not* a reply from the target machine.

Comment: a network problem? so how can the same domain return "connection refused" for one and "no route to host" for another port, on the same domain?

Comment: Maybe your firewall or proxy is blocking the other port so that's why network problem?

Answer (score 6):

I found this post describing the issue I was facing when trying to setup a simple http page using nodejs on a Public Cloud compute node.

This command did the trick for me:

> iptables -F

This command flushes i.e. clears the firewall rules that are setup inside the Linux system.

Word of caution: Since I use the distributed firewall that is part of the Public Cloud VCN, I didn't really use my OS's firewall. In case you do not have an external firewall, make sure to add a firewall rule in iptables.

Answer (score 2):

Citing Ron Maupin's answer from https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/33397/debugging-no-route-to-host-over-ethernet:

> The ICMP message, "no route to host," means that ARP cannot find the layer-2 address for the destination host. Usually, this means that that the host with that IP address is not online or responding.